# Randomly select values from a given number list to add to a certain value in r

Tags: r

If I have a set of values such as

```
c(1,2,5,6,7,15,19,20)
```

and I want to randomly select 2 values where the sum equals 20. From the above list possible samples that I would like to see would be

```
[19,1], [15,5]
```

How do I do this in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random sampling to give an exact sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016047/random-sampling-to-give-an-exact-sum)

Comment: "where the sum equals 10" and "[19,1], [15,5]" are your answers? Hmm. I guess you mean sum equals 20? Please edit.

Comment: @Spacedman thank you for the point out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computes all possible combinations of your input vector, so if this is very long, this might be a problem.

```
getVal <- function(vec,val) {
  comb = combn(vec, 2)
  idx = colSums(comb) == val
  if (sum(idx)) {
      return(comb[,idx][,sample(sum(idx),1)])
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

vec = (c(1,4,6,9))
val = 10
getVal(vec,val)
>>[1] 1 9

val = 11
>>[1] FALSE
getVal(vec,val)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a small vector of values you can do an exhaustive search by working out all the combinations of pairs in the values. Example:

```
> values = c(1,2,5,6,7,15,19,20)
> pairs = matrix(values[t(combn(length(values),2))],ncol=2)
```

That is a 2-column matrix of all pairs from `values`. Now sum the rows and look for the target value of 20:

```
> targets = apply(pairs,1,sum)==20
> pairs[targets,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   19
[2,]    5   15
```

The size of `pairs` increases such that if you have 100 `values` then `pairs` will have nearly 5000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `sample()`-functie and a while-loop. It isn't the prettiest solution but a simple to implement one for sure.

First you sample two values from the vector and store them in an object, like:

```
values <- c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 15, 19, 20)

randomTwo <- sample(values, 2)
```

Then you start you while-loop. This loop checks if sum of the two sampled values modulo 10  equals 0 (I assumed you meant modulo from the examples in your question, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation to see what it does). If the operation does not equal 0 the loop samples two new values until the operation does equal zero, and you get your two values.

Here's what it looks like:

```
while (sum(randomTwo) %% 10 != 0) {
    randomTwo <- sample(values, 2)
}
```

Now this might take more iterations than checking all combo's, and it might take less, depending on chance. If you have just this small vector than it's a nice solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In a way where **you don't need to compute a inmense matrix** (way faster):

```
findpairs=function(a,sum,num){
  list=list()
  aux=1
  for (i in 1:length(a)){
    n=FALSE
    n=which((a+a[i])==sum)
    if (length(n)){
      for (j in n){
        if (j!=i){
        list[[aux]]=c(a[i],a[j])
        aux=aux+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(sample(list[1:(length(list)/2),num))
}

a=c(1,2,5,6,19,7,15,20)
a=a[order(a)]
sum=20
findpairs(a,sum,2)
[[1]]
[1]  5 15

[[2]]
[1] 1  19
```

Issue is that it gives repetition.
**edit**
Solved. Just take half of the `list` as the other half will be the same pairs the other way around.