# How to sample values in R such that the values of a column in the sample come close to a certain value?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R, see below for a simplified example.

```
x <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = 1:20,
      value = c(
        185170.35,
        260527.34,
        155287.31,
        277086.6,
        146870.56,
        272730.39,
        162454.98,
        334184.38,
        243389.81,
        252060.31,
        141124.7,
        140439.44,
        50866.52,
        242407.08,
        268531.97,
        144602.52,
        106241.04,
        89804.73,
        77238.67,
        117366.88
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -20L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

I would like to randomly sample any number of values from `x` such that:

- the sum of the `value` column in the sample is approximately `100000`
  (plus or minus 10%)
- the sample contains a number of observations that lies within a defined range (in my full dataset with 500 observations this would be 45-65 but here I only provide 20 observations so a smaller range would be sufficient)

How could I go about this?

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: I think this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016047/random-sampling-to-give-an-exact-sum

Comment: Can you better define "approximately"? Would taking just the first value fulfill this for `sum <- 1e5`? How often do you want to do this operation / how efficient needs the algorithm to be?

Comment: @Roland Sure! This is a one-time operation and the full dataset contains 500 values so I'm not too concerned about time or time-efficiency. I realise now that I should have pointed out that in the full dataset I am looking for 45-65 values to be contained in the sample, in this case obviously fewer observations would be fine but just having 1 observation meeting the condition would be an issue. For approximately, +/- 10% is acceptable. I will update the question with this information

Comment: Is it safe to assume your example data is very different than your real data?  Your example data has 17 out of 20 entries that exceed or meet your sum criteria in a single draw...

Answer (score 2):

As others stated, it is not a time-efficient way to calculate. Especially, if the likelihood that the sum of a sampled variable is about `100000` (+/- %10) is small, you will spend a great amount of time to find it.

Even, with the data example that you provided, it is impossible to do so. Why? Because the sum of the minimum two variables, which are `128106` + `77239` = `128106`, is greater than the condition you want.

Anyhow, there is a crude way to do it. But it all depends on your data distribution and your specifications.

Because the example data is not reproducible, I created a normal distribution that has the same mean score with your example data.

```
set.seed(12358)
x <- abs(rnorm(500,183419,105500))
table(x < 100000*1.10)

FALSE  TRUE 
  371   129
```

So, we have `129` values that are smaller than `110000`, which means we can sample among those variables.

In the following part, I selected only the variables that are in the range, then created a sampling of 6 variables, and loop them to find that the sum of the six sampled variables will be about 100000. You can use this code and play with parameters based on your data.

```
## Select the variables that are in the range
x <- x[x < 100000*1.1]

## Loop for sampling 
samples <- c()
i <- 0    ## Don't change this 
cond <- F ## Don't change this 


## Parameters to play
N <- 6      ## Sample size for each loop 
p <- 0.90   ## Approximation
aim <- 100000 ## The sum value you want

## Stop the loop after a given attempt
loop.break <- 30000 ## How many time you want to try

while(isFALSE(cond)) {
  
  i <- i+1
  print(i)
  
  samples <- sample(x,N)
  cond    <- sum(samples) >= aim*p & sum(samples) <= aim*(1+(1-p))
  
  if (isFALSE(cond)) {
    
    samples <- c()
    
  }
  
  if (i > loop.break) {
    break
  }
  
}
```

So, after `287` iterations I found `6` variables that satisfy your criteria.

```
 > samples
[1]  9686.948  1854.390 25752.620 14241.465 28685.067 14631.442
> sum(samples)
[1] 94851.93
```

Please note that if you increase the number of sampled variables, let's say 9, you may not find any set of variables that satisfy your criteria.

So, what can you do? Just start with 3 or 4 sample size and increase it if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborations and your solution, very much appreciated! I hadn't noticed that there was such a structural issue in the data such that two values would meet the criteria, I should have checked this first but I never would have imagined that this is an issue. In fact it points towards a bigger issue that I will need to address.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted your example data does not lend itself well to the question, so I tried to generate some fake data that makes it more suitable.

```r
x <- tibble::tibble(id = 1:500, value = runif(500, min = 1000, max = 5000))
```

Here's an ugly little function that let's you vary parameters safely so you don't put yourself in and endless search.  Hopefully the parameters are self-explanatory.

```r
sum_game <- function(attempts = 50, wanted = 100000, fudge = .1, draws = 45) {
  for (i in 1:attempts) {
    e <- sample(x = x$value, size = draws)
    d <- sum(e)
    if (d < (wanted + (wanted * fudge)) & d > (wanted - (wanted * fudge))) {
      print(paste("I found a sum of", d, "on attempt", i))
      return(e)
    } else {
      d <- NULL
      e <- NULL
    }
   }
   print("Abject failure")
   return(e)
}

solution <- sum_game(attempts = 5000)
#> [1] "I found a sum of 105117.4719017 on attempt 1060"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, really appreciate it! Indeed my data sample is unsuitable and I am surprised to see that my entire dataset turns out to deviate from some expected paramaters. This is another matter that I will have to look at.